# WPF C# DataGrid binding List with different types

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, types, datagrid

I have a problem binding a List to a DataGrid.

What I want is to have a column presenting different types, such as:

[Property 1] [String]

[Property 2] [bool]

[Property 3] [enum]

My implementation looks like this:

```
public interface IPropertyItem 
{
}

public class PropertyItem<T> : IPropertyItem
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I create a List to store these properties:

```
List<IPropertyItem> PropertyList { get; set; }
```

And bind to the data grid:

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = PropertyList;
```

The problem now is that all cells in the 2nd column presents the different datatypes as Text.

But what I want is to have a checkbox for bools, combobox for enums etc.

I would really appreciate any help with this. Been stuck with this issue for days now.

Thank you!

-- UPDATE --

Adding a DataTemplateSelector solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that allows to define cell template. Its [CellTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplateselector%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property helps to define multiple templates and use one based on type of content for example. You`ll have to write custom `DataTemplateSelector` for that purpose, but it`s quite simple.

Comment: DataTemplateSelector is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

So you looking for [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).

Example:

```
<local:DynamicTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector" />

<DataTemplate x:Key="StringTemplate">
   <TextBlock>
    <Run Text="String: " />
    <Run Text="{Binding}" />
</TextBlock>
```

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Int32Template">
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Int32: " />
    <Run Text="{Binding}" />
</TextBlock>
```

```
<Style x:Key="MyListStyle" TargetType="ListView">
<Setter Property="ItemTemplateSelector" Value="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"/>
<Setter Property="local:DynamicTemplateSelector.Templates">
    <Setter.Value>
        <local:Templates>
            <local:Template Value={x:Type String} DataTemplate={StaticResource StringTemplate}/>
            <local:Template Value={x:Type Int32} DataTemplate={StaticResource Int32Template}/>
        </local:Templates>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it following steps.

1) you need to defined the DataTemplate for each type in collection.
2) you can either assign the template in DataTrigger based on type or you can use [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx)

Hope it helps.